# Bubble Sort an Array of Structs

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I'm just about finished with an assignment but this last section is killing me. I've done research and the solutions are concepts we haven't been taught in class and are just completely over my head. I need to bubbleSort and array of structs. However I'm completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct billingInfo;
void bubbleSort(billingInfo list[], int length);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create struct with a field for zip codes and name of recepients that are being imported from text document
        struct billingInfo {
        int zipCode;
        string name;
    };

    // create array of billingInfo struct
    billingInfo recipients[20];

    // open text file and test if file opened
    ifstream dataFile("NameZip.txt");

    if (dataFile.fail())
        cout << "Can't open file." << endl;
    else cout << "File opened." << endl;

    int numElements = 0;
    while (dataFile.peek() != EOF) {
        dataFile >> recipients[numElements].zipCode;
        getline(dataFile, recipients[numElements].name);

        cout << recipients[numElements].zipCode << endl;
        cout << recipients[numElements].name << endl;
        numElements++;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(billingInfo list[], int length) {
    billingInfo temp;
    int itterator;
    int index;
    for (itterator = 1; itterator < length - itterator - length; itterator++) {
        for (index = 0; index < length - itterator; index++) {
            temp = list[index];
            list[index] = list[index + 1];
            list[index + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    enter code here

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?  Also, that's not how to spell iterator

Comment: "_Bubble sort an array of structs_" - `struct` is a reference data type and so variables of this type (objects) don't have a primitive comparable value that you can use as the parameter for sorting. You will have to evaluate the `struct` objects based on the value of a member variable of the struct. In your code, the only numeric value is held by `int zipCode`. How exactly were you asked to sort? Is it supposed to be in ascending/descending order of the zip codes' values?

Comment: Sorry to have been so vague. I'm to sort the field names alphabetically with Bubble Sort

Answer (score 0):

```
struct billingInfo
{
    int key; // Can be any key

};
typedef struct billingInfo billingInfo;

// Overload the > operator
bool operator> (const billingInfo& first,const billingInfo& second)
{
    return first.key > second.key;
}

// Make a custom Swap function for your struct
void swap (billingInfo& first,billingInfo& second)
{
    int temp;
    temp = first.key;
    first.key = second.key;
    second.key = temp;
}

// Not a single line of change in Bubble Sort Code.
// I hope the below code is bubble sort :p
void bubble_sort (billingInfo *list,int length) 
{
    for (int i=0;i<length-1;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<length-i-1;j++)
            if (list[j] > list[j+1]) // will work since we overloaded
                swap (list[j],list[j+1]); // Our custom function
}
```

Comment: Pls accept and upvote the answer if you found it correct.